# Rewrite Rule not working back reference

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewrite-module

I have this example :

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} game=MyGame
RewriteRule ^games/freeGames?$ /flash/games/%1? [L,R=301]
```

I'm redirected to the homepage. But if I use :

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} game=MyGame
RewriteRule ^games/freeGames?$ /flash/games/MyGame? [L,R=301]
```

Redirect works fine. Can you help me please ?

Another question : is possible to have in `%{QUERY_STRING}` and array ? For example MyGame, OtherGame, Biliard, etc ?

Thx in advance and sorry for my english

Comment: Try $1 instead of %1

Comment: @Bernhard The same.......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} game=MyGame
> RewriteRule ^games/freeGames?$ /flash/games/%1? [L,R=301]
> ```

In this code, the `%1` backreference is always empty, since you have not defined a captured group (ie. parenthesised subpattern) in the preceding `RewriteCond` directive. So, the resulting URL is *always* `/flash/games/` (your "homepage" I presume).

You need to define the captured group by surrounding the string/regex in parenthesis), for example:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} game=(MyGame)
```

> Another question : is possible to have in %{QUERY_STRING} and array ? For example MyGame, OtherGame, Biliard, etc ?

If you need to match multiple items then you can use *alternation* in the captured group. For example:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} game=(MyGame|OtherGame|Biliard|etc.)
```

Now it will match "MyGame" or "OtherGame" or "Biliard" etc, and whatever matches is saved in the `%1` backreference.